What may be causing my Wi-Fi connectivity to degrade throughout the day? (FritzBox 7490, macOS 14.7.1)
I have been facing the following issue for at least six months, gone through it with my ISP’s support but since they appear not to have a clue, I am hoping to find at least some understanding here.
I have been having a FTTH 1 Gbps service with my ISP for the last 3.5 years. In general it has been quite good, with Wi-Fi speeds reaching up to 750/350 Mbps across my devices (all Apple) and across the apartment (50 m2).
Around February 2024 download speed dropped to 20 Mbps: we replaced the modem/router (a Huawei all-in-one machine).
Around May I started to experience a strange issue: everything was working well apart from downloads from the Mac App Store and macOS updates. Those were capped at 2 MB/s download while everything else stayed at 80+. After checking that tethering with my iPhone was allowing MAS- and macOS-updates at the same speed as the maximum provided by my 4G connectivity, the ISP replaced the modem/router once again.
This time, they gave me a FritzBox 7490. Initially all went well, then, after a day or so, I started to experience connectivity drops (like no network) across all my devices roughly a dozen times per day. The speed was often capped at 100 Mbps for no apparent reason. We changed the Ethernet cable from the modem to the router (this FritzBox is not an all-in-one), it improved for a few hours and then went back to <100 Mbps. They checked all cables, checked the modem, changed it (they called it “bridge” also).
Now it is no longer disconnecting but the speed never reached back the original 750+/350+. Connecting directly via Ethernet gives 920, so close to the theoretical limit of the line. Wi-Fi though, is very unstable, never goes beyond 500, often stalling around 200.
I even wondered if my 2023 MacBook Pro (M3 Max) with its Wi-Fi 6E may have issue communicating with the FritzBox which has only 802.11ac (Wi-Fi 5?). The 2018 iPad Pro, though, is even worse, not going beyond 250 Mbps. You may ask what do I need this speed for: I test software and I need to download several new versions per day.
My ISP says they tried everything and they told me to just use the cable, but can you help me understand why the Wi-Fi is degrading so much during the day? If I disconnect the Ethernet cable from the router, wait a few seconds, and plug it again, it goes back to 600 for a while, they plummets down again.
Do you have any idea what this may be and what I could do?
Perhaps I could buy my own router to use with their modem? Any idea or advice here?

Have you tested device to device transfers to test Wi-Fi or only to other devices over the internet ? Device to device will actually tell you things about the Wi-Fi, device to internet has so many extra factors involved you cant tell if its the wifi or something else. Think ISP overbooking, slow server, bad peering, ...

How can I test (or know that I tested) device to device? I have used Speedtest app by Ookla, then downloaded software and watched real speed, which was disappointing.

With device to device i mean from one device within your network to another device within your network. This way you can see your real throughput without your internet connection or anything on the internet being the bottleneck. Lets say you can transfer a file within your network at 500mbit, but only get 100mbit over the internet, its not your local Wi-Fi but an internet connectivity problem. Then you can look into wether its your¨connection or something further down the line causing issues.

OP, like what @Silbee says, you can in fact test whether the WiFi is the problem much simpler: ethernet to your router, and see if the speed is better or the same. Because if it is better, than it is the wireless signal that is the problem. If worse, then it is either the router itself of the internet itself.
